# Update картинки(blob), которая хранится базе данных, используя jsf

Tags: java, изображения

Как правильно это сделать - извлекаю картинку сервлетом и показываю ее на странице с помощью  - все ОК, но обновлять то надо с помощью ?!
Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Если потребуется дополнительная информация, напишите!

Comment: С базой работаете напрямую через JDBC или через ORM?

Comment: Напрямую через jdbc

Answer (score 0):

some_page.xhtml

```
...
<h:graphicImage id="image"  ... />

<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{someBean.image}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{someBean.save}" render="image" />
    </h:inputFile>
</h:form>
...
```

SomeBean.java

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean implements Serializable {
    private static final String QUERY = "insert into some_table (image) values (?)";

    private Part image;

    @Resource(name="jdbc/db")
    private DataSource ds;

    public void setImage(Part image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Part getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void save() {
        try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(QUERY)) {

            try (InputStream input = file.getInputStream()) {
                ps.setBinaryStream(1, input, (int) image.getSize());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch (IOException exc) {
                // Обработка ошибки ввода/вывода
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException exc) {
            // Обработка ошибки БД
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, для редактирования image сначала нужно извлечь из базы, потом "связать" с <h:inputFile> и затем делать update?

Comment: В приведённом коде инпут уже связан бином осуществляющим загрузку изображения. Чего ещё вам не хватает?